# How to catch UIWebView crash in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, try-catch, swift2

I am trying to display a downloaded file in a `UIWebView`. This works well for many file types, including `pptx` files.

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Some PowerPoint files, however, crash the web view. In my project, it is not feasible to parse the file type and dynamically modify the loading process.

Thus, I would simply like to catch the crash, abort the loading of the request and inform the user that it is not possible to display this file.

How can this be accomplished with Swift error handling? I would prefer not to drop back to some Objective-C hack to emulate the try-catch-finally pattern in Swift.

Comment: what are you calling crash? which kind of crash is it? 
Note: try-catch are now implemented in swift 2.

Comment: It is an exception breakpoint (just discovered that switching that off, there is no crash). Difficult to find out any details (no messages in console). - No, the Swift 2 try-catch is something different.